# Смена прозрачности при клике

Tags: android, ui

Необходимо вручную составить кнопку из картинок стадий, но в принципе, стадия нажатия отличается от обычной только прозрачностью. Можно ли настроить как то `selector`, что бы при клике был тот же битмап, только по прозрачнее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ммм конечно, но зачем ? не стоит городить лишние сущности, придется либо писать свой элемент, либо каждый раз обрабатывать эту ситуацию программно
[если  все таки очень хочется познать толк ....](http://habrahabr.ru/post/107757/)

Comment: Что бы не хранить лишний битмап для каждой кнопки.

Comment: ресурсы хэшируются, по факту вы будете хранить один битмэп (для каждого состояния естественно )

Comment: Так мне же тогда в любом случае в проекте нужно будет для каждой кнопки хранить два битмапа? А так я бы хранил только один.

Comment: да, но в памяти было бы все равно два + затраты на преобразование битмэпа - решать вам 
«Преждевременная оптимизация — это корень всех бед»   
©Дональд Кнут

Comment: "Так мне же тогда в любом случае в проекте нужно будет для каждой кнопки хранить два битмапа? "  два битмэпа на ВСЕ кнопки такого типа, да и не важно где еще будет использоваться данный битмэп